# Perl copy files to remote host (Windows to Windows)

Tags: perl

Not able to copy files to remote location from localmachine

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy

foreach my $All_Anr_File (@all_file)
{
    unless ($seen{$All_Anr_File}) 
    {
       # if we get here, we have not seen it before
        push(@UniqueAnr, $All_Anr_File);
        $seen{$All_Anr_File}++;

    }
}


foreach my $Anr_File (@UniqueAnr)
{
    (my $dir = $Anr_File) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
    my $new_dir= make_path("\\\\star\\\\8x26\\test\\$dir");  # remote path
    copy($Anr_File, $new_dir) or die "Copy failed for file $Anr_File: $!";
}
```

Comment: "Not able" is not an error message. What did `$!` say?

Comment: Copy failed for file C:\Dropbox\abc\traces_com.android.gallery3d_01-22-2014_01-15-54.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: you're not checking if make_path worked. Read the File::Path documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scalar context, the `make_path` function from [`File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aPath) doesn't return the path just created - it returns the number of *steps* in the path that were created.

You also have a superfluous double-backslash *after* `star` in `"\\\\star\\\\8x26\\test\\$dir"`. I'm not sure whether this will affect the result. It is tidier and more reliable to use single quotes so that most backslashes don't need to be escaped, and [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) to build native file paths.

It is also best practice to use lower-case and underscore for local variable names. Capitals are reserved for globals like package names.

Your code should look something like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use File::Spec;

my @all_file;
my %seen;

# populate @all_file

my @unique_anr = grep !$seen{$_}++, @all_file;

for my $anr_file (@unique_anr) {
  (my $dir = $anr_file) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
  my $new_dir = File::Spec->catdir('\\\\star\8x26\test', $dir);
  make_path($new_dir);
  copy($anr_file, $new_dir) or die "Copy failed for file $anr_file: $!";
}
```